# ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 90, not 91

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have the following **dataframe** that I generated using `print(df_eda.head(20))`

[image]

And I am using the code below to plot data between **day1 to day 90**

```
# Day 1 ~ 90
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15, 40))
for day in range(1,91):
    ax = plt.subplot(18, 5, day)
    price = df_eda.loc[df_eda.day == day, 'price'].values
    mean = price.mean().round(3)
    std = price.std().round(3)
    skew = (3*(mean - np.median(price))/price.std()).round(3)
    if skew >= 1.5:
        plt.hist(price, alpha = 0.7, bins = 50, color = 'red')
    elif skew <= -1.5:
        plt.hist(price, alpha = 0.7, bins = 50, color = 'blue')
    else:
        plt.hist(price, alpha = 0.7, bins = 50, color = 'gray')
    plt.title(f'day{day}')
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.xlabel('')
    plt.ylabel('')
    plt.text(0.25, 0.9, f'mean : {mean}',  ha='left', va='center', transform=ax.transAxes)
    plt.text(0.25, 0.8, f'std : {std}',  ha='left', va='center', transform=ax.transAxes)
    plt.text(0.25, 0.7, f'skew : {skew}',  ha='left', va='center', transform=ax.transAxes)
```

[image]

Now I want to use the code below to plot data between **day 91 to 181** by changing start/end values within range().

```
# Day 91~180
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15, 40))
for day in range(91,181):
    ax = plt.subplot(18, 5, day)
    price = df_eda.loc[df_eda.day == day, 'price'].values
    mean = price.mean().round(3)
    std = price.std().round(3)
    skew = (3*(mean - np.median(price))/price.std()).round(3)
    if skew >= 1.5:
        plt.hist(price, alpha = 0.7, bins = 50, color = 'red')
    elif skew <= -1.5:
        plt.hist(price, alpha = 0.7, bins = 50, color = 'blue')
    else:
        plt.hist(price, alpha = 0.7, bins = 50, color = 'gray')
    plt.title(f'day{day}')
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.xlabel('')
    plt.ylabel('')
    plt.text(0.25, 0.9, f'mean : {mean}',  ha='left', va='center', transform=ax.transAxes)
    plt.text(0.25, 0.8, f'std : {std}',  ha='left', va='center', transform=ax.transAxes)
    plt.text(0.25, 0.7, f'skew : {skew}',  ha='left', va='center', transform=ax.transAxes)
```

And this code gives me the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-247-a5208b4f991c> in <module>
      2 fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15, 40))
      3 for day in range(91,181):
----> 4     ax = plt.subplot(18, 5, day)
      5     price = df_eda.loc[df_eda.day == day, 'price'].values
      6     mean = price.mean().round(3)

c:\users\10290313\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in subplot(*args, **kwargs)
   1140 
   1141     fig = gcf()
-> 1142     ax = fig.add_subplot(*args, **kwargs)
   1143     bbox = ax.bbox
   1144     axes_to_delete = []

c:\users\10290313\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py in add_subplot(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1400                     # more similar to add_axes.
   1401                     self._axstack.remove(ax)
-> 1402             ax = subplot_class_factory(projection_class)(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1403 
   1404         return self._add_axes_internal(key, ax)

c:\users\10290313\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_subplots.py in __init__(self, fig, *args, **kwargs)
     37 
     38         self.figure = fig
---> 39         self._subplotspec = SubplotSpec._from_subplot_args(fig, args)
     40         self.update_params()
     41         # _axes_class is set in the subplot_class_factory

c:\users\10290313\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\gridspec.py in _from_subplot_args(figure, args)
    688                 if num < 1 or num > rows*cols:
    689                     raise ValueError(
--> 690                         f"num must be 1 <= num <= {rows*cols}, not {num}")
    691                 return gs[num - 1]   # -1 due to MATLAB indexing.
    692         else:

ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 90, not 91
```

Please note that I want to use day in my for loop, and the loop need to begin from **day 91**
Many thanks for your help

Comment: Shot in the dark, but try using plt.subplots() to create a new figure and axes at the same time: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html#a-figure-with-just-one-subplot  I think it's getting confused because it expects you to have only 90 subplots for one figure.

Comment: Is it obvious that you need `ax = plt.subplot(18, 5, day-90)`?